# Error en kotlin Logcat: libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.input.resample_latency_ms"

Tags: kotlin

I want to tell you about a problem that I am having recently in android-kotlin, I have a function to upload an image to firebase storage, it runs fine but when it is executed it throws me the following error in the logcat

libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.input.resample_latency_ms"

and it doesn't say anything else, everything runs fine, a Toast is displayed and the new activity opens, but at the same time that it opens, the app closes completely, I've already done these functions before and I hadn't had a problem until last week I tried to do it through a dialog fragment and it gave me the same error, I need help because before I thought it was for doing the function from the dialog and now the same thing happened to me.

I don't know what I can try since I don't understand where the error comes from
I had really resigned myself to the dialog fragment that only had to upload information to the realtime database, but now the problem keeps appearing and I can't find an answer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.